# Is it possible to capture video/audio on the browser while ensuring it is a live feed?

Tags: audio, video, browser, capture, livenessprobe

My problem is that using basic HTML5 solutions do not guarantee the video is live, it can be uploaded from disk (pre-recorded) or a virtual camera can be used to send a fake feed. Is this even possible on the browser?

I tried using HTML5 to capture audio/video and it works but when sending the file to the server I realized a file from disk can be sent or a virtual camera can be used.